# Proving a family of open intervals is an open cover of the interval $(0,1)$

Tags: real-analysis

Prove the family $\mathcal{F}$ of open intervals given by $$I_n=\left\{\,x\in \mathbb R\mid \frac{1}{n+2}<x<1-\frac{1}{n+2}\right\}\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;n\in \mathbb N$$

is a open cover of the interval $I =(0,1)$. Does there exist a finite subfamily of $\mathcal{F}$ that can cover I?

**My solution:** It can be noticed that the enumerable union of given open intervals is
$$\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}I_n = (0,1)$$

so clearly $(0,1)\subseteq \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}I_n$ is true. But examples in the book are proven more rigorously so I tried that$\\,\dots$

I need to show that for any $c\in (0,1)$ c is in the interval $I_k$ for some natural number k

By Archimedes property of $\mathbb R$, for a positive c between 0 and 1 there exist a natural number k such that $0<{1\over k}<c<1$ and hence $0<{1\over {k+2}}<{1\over k}<c<1$
But from here I am **unable to find the upper bound $1-\large\frac{1}{k+2}$**

However once it is found I think it can be shown that no finite subcover is possible by contradiction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you point out, you can find $k$ such that $\frac{1}{k}\lt c$.

Since $c\lt 1$, $c=1-\epsilon$ for some $\epsilon\gt 0$. We can choose $m$ such that $$\frac{1}{m}\lt\epsilon\implies -\frac{1}{m}\gt -\epsilon\implies 1-\frac{1}{m}\gt 1-\epsilon=c$$

Let $n$ be the maximum of $k$ and $m$.

Then $$\frac{1}{n+2}\lt\frac{1}{n}\le\frac{1}{k}\lt c\lt 1-\frac{1}{m}\le 1-\frac{1}{n}\lt 1-\frac{1}{n+2}$$